# Pig Latin equivalent to PostgreSQL generate_series() function?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm using Pig to process data to create an hourly report on a daily basis. (So, I publish the report each night, with 24 rows representing the past 24 hours.) Fundamentally, I'm just doing something like this:

```
REGISTER /path/to/pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar;                         
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix();                         
DEFINE UnixToISO org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.UnixToISO();                         
DEFINE ISOToHour org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.truncate.ISOToHour();                                                                                             

absdata = LOAD 'absdata.csv' USING PigStorage(",") AS (ts:datetime, a:int, b:int);
reldata = FOREACH absdata GENERATE HoursBetween(ToDate(ISOToUnix(ISOToHour(UnixToISO(1000L*ToUnixTime(CurrentTime()))))), ToDate(ISOToUnix(ISOToHour(UnixToISO(1000L*ToUnixTime(ts)))))) AS hs, a, b;
aggdata = GROUP reldata BY hs;
report  = FOREACH aggdata GENERATE group AS hs, SUM(aggdata.a) AS a, SUM(aggdata.b) AS b;
STORE report INTO '/my/reports' using PigStorage(',','-schema');
```

The report should always have exactly 24 data rows: 1 per hour for the past 24 hours. However, I'm finding that some of the time the input data has no events for an hour of the day, and so the output row is missing.

In PostgreSQL, I'd just use `generate_series()` to generate all the hours I care about, and a quick `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to make sure I have all the rows in my report. I've found that the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` bit is straightforward in pig, but the `generate_series()` bit is not.

Is there a pig equivalent to `generate_series()`? Generating `datetime` objects directly would be ideal, but generating an `int` sequence would be just fine too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another relation with >24 rows, use RANK function on that relation, then order by rank column, limit 24 and then choose only rank column. Now you have a relation with exact 24 rows with each row representing 1 hour.
Left outer join this relation with your final report relation.